# How to reverse the functioning of regexp matching in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, regex, match

Let us say I have a table **users** table with a column **name** and it has the following records:

- charlie
- sheen
- charl
- een
- arnold

Can I get the records that will match with "charlie sheen" without looping each item?

To be more specific: Is there a way to fetch records that contain fields that are substrings of a given string?

Comment: use WHERE name IN ('charlie', 'sheen') to select records matching set of other records, if you already have all the records localy then looping is minor overhead.

Comment: @drk: this will not have "een" in the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do what you want:

```
select * from people
    where 'charlie sheen' regexp name;
```

[See the SQLFiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6597b/1).

Keep in mind that this will be inefficient, though: by the very nature of the problem, you will have to treat every single row as a regex to see if it matches.

There will also be problems if the `name` column could contain characters that have a special meaning within a regex.

**Edit:** also worth mentioning is that if you allow non-trusted users to enter names in the database (such as from a website), treating it as a regex is a potential security problem.

Comment: thank you so much... this solves the issue, but can you please elaborate on what the security issue it could create? Sorry, I dont understand .. thanks again :)

Comment: @ZX12R, a regex can be formulated that will take a very long time to run, thus bogging down your system by using up all the resources.  See Wikipedia on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS

Comment: If your real world use case is like the example, and you are just storing names, you could easily eliminate that problem by only allowing the names to consist of letters.

Comment: wow... never knew about ReDos! thank you

Answer (score -2):

To get all data that is like a given substring i use this.

select * from [table] where [column] like %charlie sheen%

Comment: You have misunderstood the question.